# QML ListView contentHeight property value is incorrect

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I have a QML page with a GridLayout that contains the page title, ListView and close button:

```
GridLayout {
    columns: 1
    rows: 5

    anchors.fill: parent

    <page title item>....

    ListView
    {
        id: list
        spacing: 15

        model: logModel

        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        delegate: Item {
            implicitWidth: parent.width
            implicitHeight: grid.height

            RowLayout
            {
                id: grid
                spacing: 0
                width: parent.width
                height: commentLabel.implicitHeight

                <icon>....

                Label {
                    id: commentLabel
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: comment
                    wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }

    <close button>...
}

Component.onCompleted:
{
    console.log("list.contentHeight = ", list.contentHeight, "list.height = ", list.height)
}
```

when I bind ListView to a model (logModel) that contains items with `comment` property that contains relatively long multiline text and check `contentHeight` property of ListView from `Component.onCompleted` I get the value 161 that is obviously too small (actually it should be greater than 500, because ListView height property value is 461 and it is not enough for all the items).

So I cannot figure out what this 161 is. The only guess is that it is something close to the content height with single-line items (not multiline), but it is not clear what is the logic behind that.

My QT version is 5.13.2.

**EDIT1:**

The full source code:

ChangeLogPage.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Page
{
    id: root

    property alias model: list.model

    background: Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
    }

    function close()
    {
        stack.pop()
    }

    SystemPalette {
        id: palette
    }

    GroupBox
    {
        id: box

        background: Rectangle {
            color: palette.base
        }

        anchors.margins: 15
        anchors.fill: parent

        GridLayout {
            columns: 1
            rows: 5

            anchors.fill: parent

            ListView
            {
                id: list

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                //It is not clear why, but there is an enough left margin.
                Layout.leftMargin: 0
                Layout.rightMargin: 0

                Layout.topMargin: 15
                Layout.bottomMargin: 20

                //Looks like it is only vertical spacing.
                spacing: 15

                clip: true

                delegate: Item {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: grid.height

                    RowLayout
                    {
                        id: grid
                        spacing: 0
                        width: parent.width
                        //height: commentLabel.height

                        Label {
                            //id: commentLabel
                            Layout.fillWidth: true
                            text: comment //qsTr(comment)
                            wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                        }
                    }
                }

                ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
            }

            Button {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                text: qsTr("Close")
                onClicked: close()
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        console.log("list.contentHeight = ", list.contentHeight, "list.height = ", list.height)
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import LinesGame 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 640
    title: "Test"

    Component {
        id: listModelComponent
        ListModel {
            id: model
        }
    }

    StackView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        id: stack
    }

    function showChangeLogPage(beginIndex, endIndex)
    {
        if (beginIndex < endIndex)
        {
            //var component = Qt.createComponent("ChangeLogModel.qml")
            //var logModel = component.createObject(this)

            var logModel = listModelComponent.createObject(this);

            for (var i = beginIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
            {
                //i.toString()
                logModel.append({comment: qsTr("The advertising was added, but it is shown only when you start a new game or load a saved game. Support the developers, tap on the advertising!")})
            }

            stack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("ChangeLogPage.qml"), {model: logModel})
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        showChangeLogPage(0, 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set the size of the `ListView`.

Comment: @folibis There are `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight: true` in the ListView (updated the code).

Comment: I highly recommend you to post [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the pseudocode. It could help if someone want to test the code.

Comment: @folibis see EDIT1